# ParametricPlot3D coloring based on whether function located inside/outside of another parametric function

Tags: plotting, color, parametric-functions, mesh, conditional

I have two parametric shapes: an inclined ring and an elliptic cone whose vertex lies along the x axis.

```
ring[u_,v_,ψ_,α_]:={v Cos[u] Cos[α] Cos[ψ]-v Sin[u] Sin[α],v Cos[α] Sin[u]+v Cos[u] Cos[ψ] Sin[α],-v Cos[u] Sin[ψ]}

cone[u_,v_,Req_,obl_,r_,ψ_,α_]:={u,(Req (r-u) Cos[v] Cos[ψ Sin[α]])/r+(Req (r-u) Sin[v] Sin[ψ Sin[α]])/(r Sqrt[Cos[ψ Cos[α]]^2/(1-obl)^2+Sin[ψ Cos[α]]^2]),(Req (r-u) Cos[ψ Sin[α]] Sin[v])/(r Sqrt[Cos[ψ Cos[α]]^2/(1-obl)^2+Sin[ψ Cos[α]]^2])-(Req (r-u) Cos[v] Sin[ψ Sin[α]])/r};
```

when plotted, these two shapes intersect each other something like this (depending on input parameters):

[image]

Hopefully it's clear from the image that the cone intersects the ring, leaving part of the ring inside of the cone and part of the ring outside of it.

What I actually want is, instead of displaying both ring and cone, I want to color parts of the ring differently depending on whether it is inside or outside of the cone.

Your answer does not have to be specific to the messy equations I have listed above. What I want boils down to, "how do I set the colors of a parametric plot as a conditional of a different parametric equation?" I have tried all sorts of [`MeshShading`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) options, but I can't seem to get it to work.

In case it matters: the arguments of `ring` are: the azimuthal angle `u`, the radial extent of the ring `v`, the magnitude of the tilt out of the XY plane `psi`, and the XY orientation of the ring's normal vector `alpha`. The unique arguments of `cone` are: the semimajor axis of the cone at x=0 `Req`, the distance of the vertex away from the origin `r`, and the oblateness of a YZ cross-section of the cone `obl`.

EDIT: as requested, here is the exact code to make the above figure.

```
Req = 60300000.;
obl = .25;
au = 1.496*10^11;
r = 10*au;
\[Psi] = 27*Pi/180.;
\[Alpha] = 0*Pi/180.;
ringstart = Req + 7000000.;
ringend = Req + 80000000;

lightcone[u_,v_,Req_,obl_,r_,\[Psi]_,\[Alpha]_]:={u,(Req (r-u) Cos[v] Cos[\[Psi] Sin[\[Alpha]]])/r+(Req (r-u) Sin[v] Sin[\[Psi] Sin[\[Alpha]]])/(r Sqrt[Cos[\[Psi] Cos[\[Alpha]]]^2/(1-obl)^2+Sin[\[Psi] Cos[\[Alpha]]]^2]),(Req (r-u) Cos[\[Psi] Sin[\[Alpha]]] Sin[v])/(r Sqrt[Cos[\[Psi] Cos[\[Alpha]]]^2/(1-obl)^2+Sin[\[Psi] Cos[\[Alpha]]]^2])-(Req (r-u) Cos[v] Sin[\[Psi] Sin[\[Alpha]]])/r};

rings[u_,v_,\[Psi]_,\[Alpha]_]:={v Cos[u] Cos[\[Alpha]] Cos[\[Psi]]-v Sin[u] Sin[\[Alpha]],v Cos[\[Alpha]] Sin[u]+v Cos[u] Cos[\[Psi]] Sin[\[Alpha]],-v Cos[u] Sin[\[Psi]]};

lightconeplot[Req_,obl_,r_,\[Psi]_,\[Alpha]_,start_,stop_]:=ParametricPlot3D[lightcone[u,v,Req,obl,r,\[Psi],\[Alpha]],{v,0,2Pi},{u,start,stop},
    Mesh->None,
    PlotStyle->{Blue,Opacity[0.3]},
    PlotPoints->30
 ];

Show[{
        ParametricPlot3D[rings[u, v, \[Psi], \[Alpha]], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v,ringstart,ringend},PlotStyle -> White, PlotPoints -> 30],
        lightconeplot[Req, obl, 8*Req, \[Psi], \[Alpha], -4*Req, 4*Req]
}, 
    ViewPoint -> 10*{0, 1, 1},
    Axes -> False, 
    Boxed -> False
]
```

I am working in Mathematica 10. This code should be directly pastable.

Comment: Can you please share all the code you are using to make that plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler example is that of two spheres intersecting, so I'll use that:

```
sphere1[u_, v_] := {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}
sphere2[u_, v_] := {0.8, 0, 0} + {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}

ParametricPlot3D[{
  sphere1[u, v],
  sphere2[u, v]
  }, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A trick that can be used for this case and for your case is to plot the region that intersects separately from the region that doesn't intersect. Like this:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  sphere1[u, v], {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  RegionFunction -> (Norm[{0.8, 0, 0} - {#, #2, #3}] > 1 &),
  Mesh -> {Subdivide[Pi, 15], Subdivide[2 Pi, 30]}
  ],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  sphere1[u, v], {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
  RegionFunction -> (Norm[{0.8, 0, 0} - {#, #2, #3}] < 1 &),
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Mesh -> {Subdivide[Pi, 15], Subdivide[2 Pi, 30]}
  ],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All that is needed is to be able to write a function that says whether a point should be considered part of the region being plotted or not.

The purpose of using the `Mesh` option is to make sure that the meshes in the two different regions align.

If you can't find a region function for the region you're interested in then you may resort to creating the corresponding regions (e.g. with `ImplicitRegion`) and then using the `RegionMember` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a huge step in the right direction. I was unaware that those functions exist. I don't think a single inequality can describe the boundary set by my intersection. How would I actually use `ImplicitRegion` and `RegionMember` in a `ParametricPlot3D` environment? I am only seeing them be used as setup functions for `RegionPlot`.

Comment: @ahle6481 In this particular case it would work to replace the given `RegionFunction` with `(RegionMember[Ball[{0.8, 0, 0}, 1], {#, #2, #3}] &)`. This is because `Ball` can be used as a region. I mentioned `ImplicitRegion`, which can take the place of `Ball`, just to point out that the region functionality offers a very general solution. As long as you can write down inequalities to describe the region, it will work.

Comment: Apologies for still not getting it. This approach makes sense to me, but I am struggling with the syntax. With `ImplicitRegion`, I tried to make one of the above spheres only partially display with the option `RegionFunction -> (RegionMember[
    ImplicitRegion[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2 == 1 && #1 < 0. && #2 > 
       0.0, {#1, #2, #3}]] &)` but I a get an error stating that it is not a boolean. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: First define `reg = Region@ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x < 0. && y > 0, {x, y, z}];` and then use `(RegionMember[reg, {#, #2, #3}] &)`.

Comment: Great that worked! Note for other users: I am using Mathematica 10, which does not include `Region`. However, simply removing the `Region` function (`reg=ImplicitRegion...`) it worked exactly how I expected it to.